# When connected to work VPN, will my internet activity be visible?

Tags: vpn

If I connect to my work's VPN using my own personal home laptop, will my work be able to see my internet activity?

Meaning, will my DNS requests go via my works VPN or my local ISP?

Comment: This entirely depends on the configuration of the VPN, if that is the case for you, is not possible to tell without specific knowledge of your VPN.  This knowledge is only something an Administrator would have access to.

Comment: If you use IPsec VPN Split Tunnel, yes. Same as any internet.

If you use Microsoft PPPtP VPN, normally no, but it is less secure than IPsec.

Comment: If it is a vpn service that uses software like Mulvad and others, only the vpn server you are connected to can see all your traffic. You can test to see if you have any dns leaks while using the vpn by visiting this page>>>>https://www.grc.com/dns/dns.htm

Comment: Note that routing all traffic through the VPN might be considered a security feature that you (or your organization) might not want to disable. Like any "hacker" (or spyware) who has gained access to the workstation will be disconnected as soon as the VPN connection is started. Next, it then depends on the security of the VPN server/company network whether or not such unwanted traffic could be re-established through the VPN server.

Answer (score 0):

A VPN can act in different ways, and you need to work out how yours is working. There are 2 things to look for which will likely answer your question.

1. Look at the routing table on the VPN gateway. If the VPN adds a default gateway or  a route for 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 (with a corresponding route 128.0.0.0/netmask 128.0.0.0) then almost all traffic is being routed across the VPN and your Internet traffic will be visible to your employer.
2. Check if your DNS has been changed to go through the DNS server or to your employers DNS. This would not enable your employer to see traffic, but could give them an indication what domains you are visiting.  (It may also have legitimate purpose - ie allowing resources only available within the company network to resolve)

Comment: for example at home I use openvpn to block a site, when logged into my works VPN I can access the blocked sites.  So is it obvious my DNS queries are being sent to work vpn?

Comment: No. But what you have written above does not make much sense. (Ab)Using openvpn to block a site? Is the VPN on your PC or router? What nameservers is your PC using, and do traceroutes to it show they are going via the VPN?

Comment: I am using openvpn at home, my routers DNS is pointing to opendns.  In opendns I block  a website, only when logged into my works vpn on my home laptop I can access the blocked site.  If I end my work vpn connection, the site is blocked again.  I'll try traceroute never tried using it before.

Comment: how do I look at the routing table for my VPN?  I'm on OSX.   I tried ```netstat -nr``` but not sure which records are for my VPN

Comment: I don't have a Mac, so I'll leave googling this up to you. Note that DNS server IPS are not reflected in the routing table. Something else for you to Google.

Comment: It sounds like your DNS is not going through your VPN.